MySQL と MariaDB の一番の違いは、商用サポートの有無ですか？
MySQL と MariaDB の違いについて改めて調べているのですが、一番の違いは、商用サポートの有無ですか？
商用サポートを受けない場合、MySQL を選択するメリットは何かありますか？
※エンタープライズ向けではないMySQLというのが、よく分かりません。

参考: MariaDB と MySQL の違いはなんですか? - AWS

MariaDB にも Enterprise 版 (商用サポートあり) が存在します。 https://mariadb.com/pricing/

MySQLもMariaDBもエンタープライズ向け有償サポートがありますので、「商用サポートの有無」に関しては違いはありません。
では、何が「一番の違い」かと言われると、人によって「一番」は違うので、主観性が高すぎて一般的な回答は難しいです。私個人の主観では、「一番の違い」はjson型の扱い方なのですが、json型を使わない場合はどうでもいい違いなので、あなたや他の人にとっても「一番」なのかまではわかりません。
